# Google Line Chart: dashed section

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Is it possible to style just one segment of a Google Line Chart as a dashed line? Like this:

[image]

There is a `certainty` role that can achieve that but with at least two segments, because "the segment between two data points is certain if and only if both data points are certain" (See https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way but is more than hack that an official solution, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/TomKarachristos/mt76jguz/) is an example:

```
 data.addColumn({type:'boolean',role:'certainty'}); // certainty col.

      data.addRows([
        [1,  41.8, true],
        [2,  32.4, true],//duplicate this
        [2,  32.4, false],
        [3,  25.7, true],
        [4,  10.5, true],
        [5,  10.4, true],
        [6,  7.7, true],
        [7,  9.6, true],
        [8,  10.6, true],
        [9,  14.8, true],
        [10, 11.6, true],
        [11, 4.7, true],
        [12, 5.2, true],
        [13, 3.6, true],
        [14, 3.4, true]
      ]);
```

[image]